# How do I format Time in [h]:mm excel format using format() function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to format time in [h]:mm format using VBA?

[h]:mm format in excel would show 25 hours as 25:00, 125 hours as 125:00

I've tried several things such as:

```
format(datetime, "[h]:mm")
format(datetime, "H:mm")
format(datetime, "hh:mm")
```

None of these have the desired effect. I've also had a look through the MS help and can't find anything useful.

Comment: What are you getting **instead** of what you expect to get?  How is `datetime` declared, and how is it populated?

Comment: datetime is just a double variable. and the functions give different results. hh:mm is the closest, but just gives hours upto 24 hours, 25 hours shows as 01:00

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the TEXT worksheet function via the application object, as so:

```
  x = Application.Text(.294,"[h]:mm")
```

Answer (score 4):

JFC beat me to it, but here's what I came up with anyway...

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print FormatHM(24 / 24)       '24:00
    Debug.Print FormatHM(25 / 24)       '25:00
    Debug.Print FormatHM(48 / 24)       '48:00
    Debug.Print FormatHM(48.6 / 24) '48:36
End Sub

Function FormatHM(v As Double) As String
    FormatHM = Format(Application.Floor(v * 24, 1), "00") & _
                 ":" & Format((v * 1440) Mod 60, "00")

End Function
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write this. It's a very nice solution, I gave an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

not with the format function, but you can use `Range(MyData).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like VBA's `Format` function has no built-in way of doing this. (Eyes rolling.)

This home-made function will do the trick:

```
Function HoursAndMinutes(datetime As Date) As String
    Dim hours As Integer
    Dim minutes As Integer
    hours = Int(datetime) * 24 + Hour(datetime) ' the unit of Date type is 1 day
    minutes = Round((datetime * 24 - hours) * 60)
    HoursAndMinutes = hours & ":" & Format(minutes, "00")
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    Dim datetime As Date
    datetime = TimeSerial(125, 9, 0) ' 125 hours and 9 minutes
    Debug.Print HoursAndMinutes(datetime) ' 125:09
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this, it's a nice way of achieving what I need. I gave it an up vote but I'm going to accept the Application.Text method as it's a bit cleaner. Sam