# excel date format not same as in vba

Tags: vba, date, excel

I found an issue for date format in excel, which the display format is not as same as the `numberformat` in vba
and I have create a test for this case.

`Regional Setting for Short Date: MM/dd/yyyy`

modules:

```
Function RetrieveNumberFormat() As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Caller    
    RetrieveNumberFormat = rng.NumberFormat       
    Set rng = Nothing
End Function

Function SetDate() As String
    Dim rng As Range    
    Set rng = Application.Caller    
    SetDate = Format(Now, rng.NumberFormat)    
    Set rng = Nothing
End Function
```

In Excel

```
Col A (Date w default format) | Col B (MM/dd/yyyy)      | Col C (dd-mmm-yyyy)     | Col D (dd/mm/yyyy)      | Col E ([$-404]mm/dd/yyyy)
=Now()                        | =Now()                  | =Now()                  | =Now()                  | =Now()
=RetrieveNumberFormat()       | =RetrieveNumberFormat() | =RetrieveNumberFormat() | =RetrieveNumberFormat() | =RetrieveNumberFormat()
=SetDate()                    | =SetDate()              | =SetDate()              | =SetDate()              | =SetDate()
```

Date with default format (Col A):

[image: Date format]

Result:

[image: Result]

May I know why Excel changed `System Date Format MM/dd/yyyy` to `m/d/yyyy`, and is there a way to workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA date formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801598/excel-vba-date-formats). Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19809413/119775) which explains a little bit of what you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for the ans, but I think that is a little bit different than my situation, it seems excel will save number format to `m/d/yyyy` (default format for US locale) when I use date format begin with `*`, so I can't distinguish the actual format or that is system format.
However it may give me a way to do something with this problem.

Comment: This question of mine and the answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9839676/973283

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Application.Text` instead.

So your SetDate function would look like

```
Function SetDate() As String
    Dim rng As Range    
    Set rng = Application.Caller    
    SetDate = Application.Text(Now, rng.NumberFormat)    
    Set rng = Nothing
End Function
```

My experience with the `Format` function is that it is not that complete.

Comment: Thanks, but my result is same, coz `rng.NumberFormat` return `m/d/yyyy`, it's no different between `Application.Text` and `Format` for this case.

Comment: How is `Format` not complete?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143746/how-do-i-format-time-in-hmm-excel-format-using-format-function-in-vba) I asked for instance.

Comment: Ha! Right, apparently I forgot that I had [answered it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11146092/119775) :-)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes I did spot that :)

Comment: Thank you!!! This was driving me crazy! The format function would format the date as it appeared in the function bar, but it wouldn't display properly in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with how your function is set up. Modified them and here are my results.

Formula Set-up:

[image: Formula]

Result:

[image: Result]

Modified functions:

```
Function RetrieveNumberFormat(rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    RetrieveNumberFormat = rng.NumberFormat
End Function

Function SetDate(rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    SetDate = Format(Now, rng.NumberFormat)
End Function
```

Please see if this works on your end.

Comment: @Alex: Based on `Region and Language` in `Control Panel`, it's `Short date: M/d/yyyy` and `Long date: ddd, MMMM, dd, yyyy`. Even if I change it to `MM/dd/yyyy`, the results are the same. :)

Comment: Thanks and I have tried, but the result are same as I did before. I have set whole column with the same date format, so I believe this not related to `Application.Caller`.
BTW, may you help to check the cell format for A1? Date with Default format should begin with *, which will affected by `regional setting`

Comment: Weird. Changed things around and I'm getting the same error you're getting. `12/06/2013` is now turning into `12/6/2013` when I used the default `Date` setting. Methinks VBA reads the date differently from how Excel reads it in the regional setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it good enough to solve my question yet, but feel free to comment or enhance this.

The problem I encounter seems that excel will save `date formats that begin with (*)` to `m/d/yyyy`, the default format for US locale (Well, Excel is created by US company), instead of actual date format.

It work fine when we input value directly in excel, excel will change the date format automatically, however, when I use VBA for output, this may produce a problem, especially when using `autofilter`.

I have enhance `SetDate` function:

```
Function SetDate(refCell As Range) As String
    If refCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" And refCell.Text = Format(refCell.Value, "Short Date") Then
        SetDate = Format(Now, "Short Date")
    Else
        SetDate = Format(Now, refCell.NumberFormat)
    End If
End Function
```

However this method still have an issue when work with date format: `dd-MMM-yyyy`, which excel will display as `dd-MM-yyyy`.

[image: dd-MMM-yyyy]