# VBA placing date format dd/mm/yyyy as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that places the current date on a table, but my VBA is placing it wrong

```
ActiveSheet.Range("K23").Value = Format(Now(), "dd mm yyyy")
```

But instead of placing 07/03/2023 is placing 03/07/2023, placing month first.
What do I need to do for VBA to put as the first date, with days first.

Comment: I would love to see a [mcve] on this. I've just tried exactly your code and it's working perfectly for me.

Comment: How do you know whether the date in `W23` is `3-Jul-2023` or `7-Mar-2023`?

Comment: Instead of putting: 07(dd)/03(mm)/2023(yyyy) as the code says He puts: 03(mm)/07(dd)/2023(yyyy). Removing the "/" fixed mt code though

Comment: Whom is "he" that you're talking about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [excel date format not same as in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414851/excel-date-format-not-same-as-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("K23")
   .Value = Date
   .NumberFormat = "dd mm yyyy"
End With
```

IMO, much better to write an actual date to a cell and then adjust the `.NumberFormat`, rather than writing a `String`.

Comment: I can't get the OP's code to replicate their issue and your code is setting `Value` as a date and then formatting the cell - which is different from what the OP is doing. Maybe the OP is just trying to display a formatted date, but they have handwritten the code instead of recording a macro, so I feel there is some intent to place text in the cell rather than a date value. Something feels odd here.

Comment: It worked perfectly, but there is still a doubt about why using "/" in the "dd/mm/yyyy" code, VBA puts the "mm" in front.
Instead of putting:
07(dd)/03(mm)/2023(yyyy)
He puts:
03(mm)/07(dd)/2023(yyyy)